# HTML5 Canvas stroke text overlap joinning part in Arabic, Hindi, Bengali etc language

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

In Arabic, Hindi, Bengali etc language, each letter joining each other while writing. But in HTML5 Canvas textStroke, these strokes are not joining. Is there any way to join these overlapping joining point?

[image: Overlaping Problem]

Picture: Problem with an overlap of joining parts

[image: These should join]

Picture: These joining parts should be joined

```
var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic");
var ctx = arabic.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px Georgia";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeText(" اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ ", 10, 100);


var hindi = document.getElementById("hindi");
var ctx = hindi.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px Georgia";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeText("हिन्दी", 10, 100);

var bengali = document.getElementById("bengali");
var ctx = bengali.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px Georgia";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeText("বেঙ্গলি", 10, 100);
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/qa9t64bd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Shadow Filter is no need to solve this problem. Just add `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";` and then add fillText. It will automaticly clip the text stroke and fillText.

```js
var arabic = document.getElementById("arabic");
var ctx = arabic.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px Georgia";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.strokeText(" اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ ", 10, 100);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fillText(" اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ ", 10, 100);


var hindi = document.getElementById("hindi");
var ctx = hindi.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px Georgia";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.strokeText("हिन्दी", 10, 100);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fillText("हिन्दी", 10, 100);

var bengali = document.getElementById("bengali");
var ctx = bengali.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px Georgia";
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.strokeText("বেঙ্গলি", 10, 100);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
ctx.fillText("বেঙ্গলি", 10, 100);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="arabic" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="hindi" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="bengali" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

JSFiddle Link - https://jsfiddle.net/1nc5owp7/1/

Comment: Of course, silly me! Got blinded by the other Q/A finally. Well done. You can unaccept mine and accept yours instead.